# PushAsync not working with ContentPage

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, content-pages

Trying to navigate from one page to another page by using

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
```

But getting,

> System.InvalidOperationException: PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage.

```
new NavigationPage(new Page2());
```

And

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new App6.Views.SplashPage());
```

Also not working

Comment: What is the type of App6.Views.SplashPage?

Comment: @EvZ ContentPage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Application.MainPage` page should be a `NavigationPage` in order to support `PushAsync` navigation method.

Example:

```
// In App.cs
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyContentPage());

// Elsewhere in your solution with respect to corner cases
await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyContentPage2);
```

[Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical) has nice examples and a good read.